Identifying delegatecalls to a target contract
A contract I am auditing (contract A) is being used via delegate call by another contract. I suspect there may be more contracts using this code as well in the same manner but I cannot prove it.
Is there any way I can identify contracts that are making delegatecalls to contract A? Are there any traces left of a delegatecall akin to internal transactionn?
Unfortunately, these transactions do not emit any events, which was a way I could use to spot them otherwise.
